# Responsive images in a slider

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive-design, slider

I am currently designing a website, one of the pages has a slider to showcase some images.

Images are different sizes and ratios.

I want to have the slider stay at the same height, whilst resizing and centring the images appropriately as the cycle through (Previously, when the next image came up, the container would resize and push the page up or down slightly).

This has been done, using the following:

```css
.event-slider {
 max-height: 250px !important;
}
.event-slider img {
 height: 28vh !important;
 margin: auto;
 width: auto !important;
}
```

I am using a 1080p display, which it looks fine in, but a friend has looked at his 720p and the images look smaller.

This is a Wordpress site using the 'SiteOrigin Slider' widget.

Screenshots of the 1080p and 720p views as I can, yet, publicly send out the link.

[1080p Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEZty.jpg)

[720p Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIqtY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about making this work.

Primarily, it's because of the 28vh value on height that's making the image's height skew. Image is 28% of the viewport's height is how that translates.

Try this instead of what you have.

```
.event-slider img {
height: 250px !important;
margin: auto;
width: auto !important;
}
```

Without looking at the site in question I think that should work.